# Loop through all the children item from an array to create JsTree Children Item

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, jstree

I'm having an issue with formatting JSON data for the jQuery JsTree. I've many children item that I'd like to show under the Root folder. However, when I can't figure out how to loop through all children item. The following code only prints 1 item from the children array. I'd like to print all the children item.

```
$children = [];

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $children['id'] = $item['id'];
    $children['text'] = $item['title'];
}

$data = [
    'id' => 1, 
    'text' => 'Root',
    'children' => $children
];

echo json_encode($data);
```

The above code print the following result:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "text":"Root",
    "children":{
        "id":"0B_J9f9IAYIKQczFkUERDUHpBYmc",
        "text":"Complete Thesis.doc"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out myself by assigning the empty array using the array key. Here's how I did it:

```
<?php
    $children = [];

    foreach ($items as $item => $value) {
        $children[$item]['id'] = $value['id'];
        $children[$item]['text'] = $value['title'];
    }

    $data = ['id' => 1, 'text' => 'Root',
        'children' => $children
    ];

    echo json_encode($data);
```

The above code returns the following result as the formatted JSON string for the JsTree:

```
{"id":1,"text":"Root","children":[{"id":"0B_J9f9IAYIKQemNzVzBhNDg2elE","text":"New Folder"},{"id":"0B_J9f9IAYIKQdkktWEREaHVLMUk","text":"New Folder"},{"id":"0B_J9f9IAYIKQX3pjUU5FTDBkUlE","text":"Erin VZBakker 4 thisis.pdf"},{"id":"0B_J9f9IAYIKQczFkUERDUHpBYmc","text":"Complete Thesis.doc"}]}
```